# countable intersection of domain of densely defined operators is dense

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(A,D(A))$ a closed densely defined  linear operator on a Banach space $X$.

It is easy to prove that $D(A^n)$ is dense in $X$.

Define now
$$D(A^\infty):=\bigcap_n^\infty D(A^n)$$
Is it true that $D(A^\infty)$ is dense in $X$?

I thought to use the Baire Cathegory theorem, but it works only for open dense sets and i don't know if the domain of the operator is open.

Comment: See for example page 6 of Pazy's book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5561-1 for a proof of this property when $A$ is the generator of a strongly continuous semigroup.